# New Question is a rewording of a question on Hold

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Aight, this new user asked [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44654/how-does-the-no-gas-start-method-actually-work#), and it was put on hold as it related to driving technique.

Now, the same user posted [this new question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/44729/why-do-cars-accelerate-when-the-clutch-is-in-the-friction-zone), which is his original question reworded to be in-scope.

Wadoowiidoo?

- Commend him on the rewording? His question is now a duplicate.
- Inform him to edit his original question (to match the 2nd one) and then close the 2nd one? Seems pedantic.
- A moderator gets in there commando-style and copy/pastes the wording of the new question as an edit of the original question? This user will not learn the proper working of SE.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is that he asked a question (eventually) that is a duplicate. That's okay since it gets the question answered but I did agree with others that the second was a duplicate.